# txt file output of multidimensional list without comma ( , )

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file-io

I have made a multidimensional list called `finalMaze` of size (n x n).
I’m not really understanding how file i/o works in python
so couldn't really edit what I had managed to put together from the internet..

```
import csv
def writeMaze(finalMaze, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(finalMaze)
```

The output is something like...

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3
```

All that I want is to get rid of that comma (`,`) between numbers. If anyone can explain how I can do it, I would very appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove comma from the `delimiter` option

```
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
```

Comment: How could I just ignore that obvious " , " in the code ? thanks!